# read the GET variables in url JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, get

Sorry for another "simple" question, but is there an easy way to read the GET variables from a URL.  example. I have a url `http://www.domain.com/page.php?var1=1`  In my case I will only have 1 variable i.e. `var1` or `var2` (the variable can change but there will only every be one per url).  All the tuts I have seen relate to arrays rather than "singletons" OK I know an array solution may be better but this is just a simple single get variable.  Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get QueryString values with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-querystring-values-with-jquery)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
var split = location.search.replace('?', '').split('=')
```

`split[0]` is your var name, and `split[1]` is your var value. You actually don't really need jQuery for that piece of code ;)

As for twiz's comment, splitting multiple variables can be done like that:

```
var split = location.search.replace('?', '').split('&').map(function(val){
  return val.split('=');
});
```

You can access variable name by `split[index][0]` and value by `split[index][1]`.

Of course you can use the second snippet instead of the first one for one variable too.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to split by '&' as well for multiple variables?

Comment: I just used '&' && '=' for the argument passed to the split function. Seemed to parse results nicely.

Answer (score 5):

I use this in my default javascript file.

```
var get = [];
location.search.replace('?', '').split('&').forEach(function (val) {
    split = val.split("=", 2);
    get[split[0]] = split[1];
});
```

Now you can use them by name:

```
get["var1"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function that returns the value of the specified var name from url if the var exists. Otherwise you will get an empty string.

```
function getUrlValue(varName) {
    var split = $(location).attr('href').split('?');
    var value = '';
    if (split.length == 2) {
        split = split[1].split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i+=1) {
            var keyValue = split[i].split('=');
            if (keyValue.length == 2 && keyValue[0] == varName) {
                value = keyValue[1];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With ES2019 to create an object:

```js
let GET = Object.fromEntries( location.search
                                      .replace( '?', '' )
                                      .split( '&' )
                                      .map( i => i.split( '=' ) ) );
```

The [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) method creates an object from an array.

For the URL `http://www.example.com/page?var1=1&var2=2` the above code returns the object

```
{
  var1: '1',
  var2: '2'
}
```